# Online migration using Database Migration Services

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure

I wanted to test online migration to azure sql db using azure database migration services.  I am following the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-azure-sql-online

But in step 7 under "[Create Migration project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-azure-sql-online)", I am unable to see online data migration under activity.  I have DMS in Central US location.

[image]

Anybody had the same issue?

Comment: I would double check on all the prerequisite especially about migration service.